# Microsoft Edge Browser not playing WAV file

Tags: wav, web-audio-api, microsoft-edge

I am trying to play a WAV file in the browser. This particular WAV file plays just fine in all browsers except IE and Edge. IE is to be expected -- it doesn't support WAV. However, it looks like it should work in Edge. I've studied the header of the file, and it looks like it is well-formed to me.

This error is printed to the console:

```
WEBAUDIO17014: Decoding error: The stream provided is corrupt or unsupported.
```

Here is the header:

```
52 49 46 46 : "RIFF"
24 30 0C 00 : file size (798,756 bytes)
57 41 56 45 : "WAVE"
66 6D 74 20 : "fmt "
10 00 00 00 : length of format (16 bytes)
01 00 : type of format
01 00 : Number of channels (1)
22 56 00 00 : Sample rate (22050)
88 58 01 00 : (Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8. 
02 00 : (BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8.1 - 8 bit mono2 - 8 bit stereo/16 bit mono4 - 16 bit stereo 
10 00 : bits per sample (16)
64 61 74 61 : "data"
00 30 0C 00 : size of data (798,720 bytes)
```

So, the two unusual things I see are:

1) It uses a sample rate of 22050. Is that supported in Edge?

2) It is a mono file. Is that supported in Edge?

I tried to look up WEBAUDIO17014 but I didn't get any relevant answers. Is there a way to get a more specific error message about what is going wrong?

Edit:
By request, here is the HTML of the page:

```
<audio src="/path/to/file.wav" preload></audio>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to switch to a more universally supported file format? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats Also can you show the code you're using to play/embed the file?

Comment: The file is generated with javascript in the browser using the web browser's microphone. There are no libraries required if I use WAV since it is such a simple format. Also, there are mp3 licensing issues that we want to avoid.

Comment: Are you on an Intranet with this, possibly triggering one of those weird compatibility provisions built into the browser? Not sure whether they're still a thing or not in Edge, but [they say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975061(v=vs.85).aspx) `If you are developing locally or on an intranet and have rendering issues for HTML5, you can add a "meta http-equiv-'X-UA-Compatible' content= " meta command, followed by "IE=edge" to the <head> block of a webpage to force Internet Explorer to use the latest standards. `

Comment: Only other thing that comes to mind is specifying the content type specifically `audio/wav`